# How to dynamically name jpeg filenames in R

Tags: r, jpeg

Suppose i have n records for which i am trying to generate n images
I am trying to give the file name as follows.

```
jpeg(file="/home/ttt...../percpackup"+str(i)+".jpeg")
```

Here 'i' runs from 1 to n .
I am getting an error message as:

```
Error in "/home/ttt...../percpackup" +  :
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
Calls: jpeg -> checkIntFormat -> gsub
Execution halted
```

Comment: In R, use `paste0()` to combine strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like :

```
(sapply(1:n , function(i){jpeg(paste0("/home/ttt...../percpackup", i, ".jpeg"))}))
```